# Typescript string split remove quotes

Tags: typescript

I have the following string, that needs to become an array of elements, by splitting it by comma character.

```
"Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4"
```

The result should be an array [Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4], without the quotes. I've tried to remove the quotes before I do the split, but somehow the result still have those quotes. Tried also to go through each array item after I did the split and remove the quote, and did not succeed. How can this be achieved?

Comment: `const str = '"Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4"'; JSON.parse(\`[${str}]\`)`

Answer (score 0):

Split then remove the first and last character of each string:

```js
const str = '"Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4"';
console.log(
  str
  .split(',')
  .map(s => s.substring(1, s.length-1))
)
```